# Delete all records from table that starts with <

Tags: php, sql

I want to delete all records from the table called comments that starts with " < " and i don't find a way to do it , how can i do it ?

I've tried do do it when i open the page but it doesn't work

```
DELETE FROM comments
WHERE b_text  LIKE '<%';
```

Comment: any chance you are saving `<` as html entity `&lt;`?

Comment: @Federkun yes i want to exclude the text that starts with "<" because of the alerts i can abuse

Comment: so, what are you saving in the database? `<` or `&lt;`?

Comment: @Federkun  i am saving "<"

Comment: then we need some more info. your query seems fine - can you pass here a few records that you think should match the query? where/how are you executing it?

Comment: it just executes when i open a page

Comment: we need more informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a typo, but your comparison `<` appears to be space-lessthan-space.

If so, that needs to be represented in the pattern:

```
DELETE FROM comments
WHERE b_text  LIKE ' < '
```